# NodeJS framework for manipulating a virtual DOM and syncing changes to a browser

Tags: node.js, dom, websocket, real-time, jsdom

I am developing a nodejs application and I am interested in manipulating a virtual representation of the DOM on the server side and then  syncing these changes to a connected browser in real time.

I know about libraries like jsdom for manipulating a virtual DOM in nodejs, and I know websockets can be used for real-time communication between the server / client,  but I am looking for a more integrated solution.

Specifically, I'm looking to manipulate a virtual representation of the DOM in my nodejs console app, similar to how you might manipulate the actual DOM in the browser using document.getElementById, .appendChild, etc.  I'm thinking something to track these DOM manipulations or changes and send these tracked changes to a connected browser in real time using something like WebSockets.  The clientside, might listen for these changes and then apply them to the actual DOM

Is there a  nodejs framework or library that provides these features, or a combination of frameworks/libraries that can be used together to achieve this? I'm most interested in using it for local debugging / as a localhost dashboard

Answer (score 0):

JSDOM supports MutationObserver which you could use to watch DOM changes and send mutation through a websocket:

```
// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
const callback = (mutationList, observer) => {
  for (const mutation of mutationList) {
    if (mutation.type === "childList") {
      console.log("A child node has been added or removed.");
    } else if (mutation.type === "attributes") {
      console.log(`The ${mutation.attributeName} attribute was modified.`);
    }
  }
};
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver